# puppet merge two variable in define

Tags: arrays, puppet, facter

We have multiple sub-interface and multiple app running on own sub-interface IP so I am trying to use `facter` variables to iterate my loop using `$name`

here are my interface in facter command output

```
ipaddress_eth0_0 => 10.3.68.98
ipaddress_eth0_1 => 10.3.68.99
ipaddress_eth0_2 => 10.3.68.100
ipaddress_eth0_3 => 10.3.68.101
```

my manifests file

```
define myapp {
     exec {"$name":
        command => /bin/sed -i 's/IP_ADDRESS=\"127.0.0.1\"/IP_ADDRESS=\"$ipaddress_eth0_$name\"/' /opt/app.$name/bin/setenv.sh
}

myapp { [ "0", "1" , "2", "3" ]: }
```

some how `$ipaddress_eth0_$name` doesn't working :( its not parsing this variable, how do I join two variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look to the inline template feature

```
   define myapp {
      $myip  =  inline_template("<%= ipaddress_eth0_${name} %>")
      exec {"$name":
        command => "/bin/sed -i 's/IP_ADDRESS=\"127.0.0.1\"/IP_ADDRESS=\"$myip\"/' /opt/app.${name}/bin/setenv.sh"
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

The stdlib library has a `getvar` (https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-stdlib#getvar) function that should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to wrap the variables with curly braces

E.g.

```
   define myapp {
      exec {"$name":
        command => /bin/sed -i 's/IP_ADDRESS=\"127.0.0.1\"/IP_ADDRESS=\"${ipaddress_eth0}_${name}\"/' /opt/app.${name}/bin/setenv.sh
   }
```

**UPDATE**

Could you wrap the command in double quotes e.g.

```
   define myapp {
      exec {"$name":
        command => "/bin/sed -i 's/IP_ADDRESS=\"127.0.0.1\"/IP_ADDRESS=\"${ipaddress_eth0}_${name}\"/' /opt/app.${name}/bin/setenv.sh"
   }
```

Comment: No it's not working, I have tried all possible combination but it is not working. It's looks simple but doesn't working...

Comment: Can you show me your fact? Is it a custom one or a core fact?

Comment: They are puppet factor not custom, check my question, I've posted them

Comment: I see, did you had the chance to wrap the command in double quotes's?

Comment: I tried all quotes, `single` `double` `()` all possible combo, believe me last three day i am doing all these

Comment: Could you supply the Vagrantfile and puppet file? So I can run them myself. Because I'm not getting the error when trying to reproduce it

Comment: Thanks for trying but i got answer it was `inline_template`